# PostgreSQL: I want to know the difference of 'cast'

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I try to convert mssql query to postgresql query.

mssql query is

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, column)
```

I know postgresql cast is two ways.

1.

```
CAST(column as VARCHAR)
```

2. column::VARCHAR

What's the difference?

Is it ok to use the second method?

Comment: If you want to implement query i think no 1 better because cast syntax with :: is PostgreSQL specific and does not conform to SQL

Comment: The two types of cast should be interchangeable, but the `::` notation is not ANSI compliant, and won't port to other databases.

Comment: CAST() is an ANSI SQL standard, CONVERT() is SQL Server function and has Some additional functionality where you can optionally specify [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)

> PostgreSQL accepts **two equivalent** syntaxes for type casts:
>
> ```
>   CAST ( expression AS type )
>   expression::type
> ```
>
> The CAST syntax conforms to SQL; the syntax with :: is historical PostgreSQL usage.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So both do the same thing, the `cast()` being standard SQL, the `::` being Postgres specific.

---

Note that there is a third way of casting (as explained in the manual)

> It is also possible to specify a type cast using a function-like syntax:
>
> ```
> typename ( expression )
> ```

But it's not recommended as the manual says: "*Obviously, this is not something that a portable application should rely on*"